# jQuery - Different actions for when clicking on TR and TR > span

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have put some data into a HTML table. When clicking on a `tr`, it adds a 'checked' attribute to the checkbox for that particular row.

However, I have several rows containing the same parent id inside a `span` - when I click the parent id, it should add a 'checked' attribute to all rows with this id. My approach was to have two different actions - one for when you click a table row

```
$('tr').on('click', function() { ... do stuff ... });
```

And  another action for when you click a `tr` inside the `span`

```
$('tr > span').on('click', function() { ... do something else });
```

Problem is, when I click on the `span` it runs the first event aswell. I tried playing around with a `:not` selector and `.not()` function, but I couldn't seem to get it to work.

Here's my code (only took the relevant parts):

```
$('tr').on('click', function() {
    // do checkbox action here
});

$('tr > span').on('click', function() {
    // do multiple checkbox actions here
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) to stop from bubbling up :

```
$('tr > span').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  // do multiple checkbox actions here
});
```